# Getting an unexpected exception in NetBeans

Tags: maven, tomcat, netbeans

I get a `ClassNotFoundException` for `org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.J2eeActionsProvider` in NetBeans:

> Annotation: while loading from
>   BinaryFileMap@b19ad5{fo=MultiFileObject@b4e1e7[Projects/org-netbeans-modules-maven/war/Lookup/org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee-J2eeActionsProvider.instance]}
>   while loading from
>   BinaryFileMap@b19ad5{fo=MultiFileObject@b4e1e7[Projects/org-netbeans-modules-maven/war/Lookup/org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee-J2eeActionsProvider.instance]}
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.J2eeActionsProvider starting from
>   SystemClassLoader[474 modules] with possible defining loaders null and
>   declared parents [org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@12c6ec2,
>   ModuleCL@4e4a22[org.netbeans.api.annotations.common],
>   ModuleCL@c7fc0e[org.openide.awt],
>   ModuleCL@7c7efa[org.netbeans.api.progress],
>   ModuleCL@5936cd[org.openide.dialogs],
>   ModuleCL@575101[org.openide.nodes],
>   ModuleCL@1a7eac9[org.openide.windows],
>   ModuleCL@a5c529[org.netbeans.modules.editor.mimelookup],
>   ModuleCL@1d36f2e[org.openide.text],
>   ModuleCL@134e1cc[org.netbeans.swing.tabcontrol], ...458 more]     at
>   org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:224)    at
>   org.netbeans.ModuleManager$SystemClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleManager.java:722)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)    at
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectapi.LazyLookupProviders.loadPSPInstance(LazyLookupProviders.java:174)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectapi.LazyLookupProviders.access$000(LazyLookupProviders.java:73)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.projectapi.LazyLookupProviders$1$1.beforeLookup(LazyLookupProviders.java:118)
>     at
>   org.openide.util.lookup.ProxyLookup.beforeLookup(ProxyLookup.java:209)
>     at
>   org.openide.util.lookup.ProxyLookup$R.myBeforeLookup(ProxyLookup.java:667)
>     at
>   org.openide.util.lookup.ProxyLookup$R.beforeLookup(ProxyLookup.java:689)
>     at
>   org.openide.util.lookup.ProxyLookup$R.myBeforeLookup(ProxyLookup.java:676)
>     at
>   org.openide.util.lookup.ProxyLookup$R.beforeLookup(ProxyLookup.java:689)
>     at
>   org.openide.util.lookup.ExcludingLookup$R.beforeLookup(ExcludingLookup.java:328)
>     at
>   org.openide.util.lookup.ProxyLookup$R.myBeforeLookup(ProxyLookup.java:676)
>     at
>   org.openide.util.lookup.ProxyLookup$R.computeResult(ProxyLookup.java:549)
>     at
>   org.openide.util.lookup.ProxyLookup$R.allInstances(ProxyLookup.java:509)
>     at
>   org.openide.util.lookup.ProxyLookup$R.allInstances(ProxyLookup.java:505)
>     at
>   org.openide.util.lookup.SimpleProxyLookup$ProxyResult.allInstances(SimpleProxyLookup.java:267)
>     at org.openide.util.Lookup.lookupAll(Lookup.java:271)   at
>   org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.ActionToGoalUtils.actionProviders(ActionToGoalUtils.java:120)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.maven.ActionProviderImpl.getSupportedActions(ActionProviderImpl.java:179)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectsRootNode$BadgingNode.canDestroy(ProjectsRootNode.java:884)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.openide.explorer.ExplorerActionsImpl.updateActions(ExplorerActionsImpl.java:258)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.openide.explorer.ExplorerActionsImpl$ActionStateUpdater.run(ExplorerActionsImpl.java:798)
>     at
>   org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1423)
>     at
>   org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.J2eeActionsProvider   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:222)
>     ... 24 more while loading from
>   BinaryFileMap@b19ad5{fo=MultiFileObject@b4e1e7[Projects/org-netbeans-modules-maven/war/Lookup/org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee-J2eeActionsProvider.instance]}

Why am I getting this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClassNotFoundException usually means that there is something broken with your installation.

In this case org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.J2eeActionsProvider registration entry is present but the associated class is not found (but typically both reside in the same module, so both should be either present or missing)